# What is the best way to bulk update for 500 documents in mongodb using java

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb

I tried to update (5-thread in each Thread 100 records) 500 records in one collection and it took 12.09 (or)14 mins.(done using bulk update). But,when I do bulk insert it took only milliSeconds(256). I need to know, why my bulk update take more time. How can i perform my bulk update in faster manner.?

Here is my test Classes,

```
 public class threadaccess {
 public static void main(String s[]){

    System.err.println("Thread starting:");
        for(int i=5;i<10;i++){
        new BulkUpdateThread(i).start();
            }
        }
}
```

BulckUpdateThread

```
 import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
 import com.mongodb.BulkWriteOperation;
 import com.mongodb.DB;
 import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
 import com.mongodb.Mongo;

 public class BulkUpdateThread extends Thread {
    int threads ;
    public BulkUpdateThread(Integer threadid){
        setName(""+threadid);
        threads=threadid;
    }
    public void run(){
        long con =(threads+1)*100;
         long no = threads*100;
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo("192.168.1.197",27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("Thread");
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("large");
        collection.setWriteConcern(new WriteConcern(1));
        BulkWriteOperation bulkop = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();

        long a =0;

        while(a > new Date().getMinutes()){

        }
        long s = new Date().getTime();
        while(no < con){
            try{


                BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
                document.put("id", no);

                BasicDBObject updatedoc = new BasicDBObject();
                updatedoc.put("id", no);
                updatedoc.put("name", "sathish003");
                updatedoc.put("age",24);
                updatedoc.put("DOB",new Date());
                BasicDBObject up = new BasicDBObject();
                up.put("$set", updatedoc);

                long start = new Date().getTime();


                bulkop.find(document).update(up);
                long end = new Date().getTime();

                 System.out.println("Thread-"+getName()+" : "+(++no)+" : "+(end-start));

            } catch (Exception iex) {
                System.out.println("Exception in thread: "+iex.getMessage());
            }

    }   bulkop.execute();
  long end = new Date().getTime();
        System.out.println("----Thread -"+threads+" StartTime: "+s+" End Time -"+end+" TimeTaken: "+(end-s));

}
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the `id` in the update? Are all the documents getting updated to the same data? If so, why not use the bulk update operations of Mongo instead of updating each document one-by-one?

Comment: use Bulk.find.update() take a good look at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/

Comment: thanks. But i am already use Bulk.find.update(). Please refer my code..

Comment: @Darth Android.   I am setting id,But is one of the field name. It's not unique(_id). Testing purpose only updated same document, using bulk update and feature I will update different document  in using bulk update.

Comment: Are you comparing the performance between update and insert ? They are different type of operations.